# How can I remove metal connectors from a thin wooden ring?

Tags: glue, epoxy, assembly

My issue is in the form of these headphone rings - I'm wanting to create new ones, but I need to extract these big metal lugs from the original, preferably without destroying them.

[image]

I believe the wood itself is Shedua, and the metal is aluminium. As far as I can tell, they're using some type of epoxy to hold it in place - any idea how I could remove this lug, without damaging either the wood or the metal?

Comment: You *might* be able to get both parts to come out of this unscathed, but I wouldn't necessarily count on it. Generally with this sort of operation you have to accept some damage to one component. Then you weight the methods/processes to maintaining the important bit (in this case the metal without question) at the cost of the other. For this specifically if it is held with epoxy you might be able to soften that with heat. Most epoxies soften at temps a domestic hair dryer can reach (slightly too hot to touch), but they soften more at higher temp, e.g. with a heatgun, but careful not to scorch.

Comment: In the future, please post your images directly within SE. It makes it much easier to see the images here than to have to click the link to Imgur. As a side note, SE uses a dedicated Imgur site to host their images, so they really end up in the same place anyway.

Comment: I know that this is a year old, but including some pics at other angles may have given us a better idea of what you were working with and allowed people to come up with some creative ideas. Of course, it would be really nice if you walked us through (in an answer) what you ended up doing.

Comment: @FreeMan - I couldn't figure how to cleanly do it, so I left the original rings intact. My current solution is remodelling the metal part, and printing it with an SLA printer. The resin isn't _quite_ as nice as the original aluminium part, but it's a reasonable alternative.

The pandemic put a spanner in this project though, as I've been unable to get into the wood shop I planned on using.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. It would be nice to give jdv an upvote for his answer - at a minimum, it'll keep your question from popping up every few months. Unless, of course, you're still hoping that _someone_ will come up with an answer for you.

Comment: @FreeMan - I did give JDV an upvote, though because my rep is low on woodworking it doesn't show up

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the parts are epoxied together there isn't much you can do. Epoxy is forever for most mortals. It depends on the kind of epoxy, but most are resistant to most common solvents. So you would have to know the exact kind and hope that you can find the appropriate solvent, and then hope it didn't destroy the material around it.

If it is some other sort of glue, then heat, steam, and patience is the order of the day. Some epoxies only fully cure with heat or UV, and there is a period where they can be softened and reworked. In this case, we don't know the kind of epoxy or whether it was heat-cured already. You could, of course, try this before moving on to more destructive  methods.

Otherwise, you are drilling out the metal piece and replacing it.

Comment: Almost all epoxies have a surprisingly low glass transition temperature. What this means is that modest heating can soften them and make it easier to prise things apart. It's like magic really, especially since the change is reversible (the glue goes back to normal when it cools).

Comment: I think that depends on the epoxy. If this was that UV curing stuff, no amount of heat is going to soften it. And many epoxies will heat-cure a second time and from that point on be pretty much permanent.

Comment: Unless I have grossly misunderstood the sources I've read, *all* epoxies and polymeric systems soften with heat, including industrial epoxies that we wouldn't typically encounter (it's just with those that the temp tends to be so much greater, 250°C or a little above, versus only 50-60° at the low end). What I think you've misconstrued is that post-cure heating can cause a further curing phase after which (i.e. *after it has re-cooled*) the epoxy is harder/tougher than it was previously. But that doesn't mean it no longer has a Tg.